# Gatling doesn't send specified number of requests per seconds

Tags: performance, gatling

I am testing my API with below **gatling3** code

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(300) during (10 minutes))).throttle(
reachRps(300) in (10 seconds),
holdFor(5 minutes),
reachRps(500) in (10 seconds),
holdFor(5 minutes)
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

what I am expecting is in first 5 minutes, gatling sends **300** requests per seconds and in the next 5 minutes, gatling sends **500** requests per seconds. However the test report shows that gatling sends **300** requests per seconds in all the 10 minutes.

[image]

why does this happen?

Comment: Is every user sending 1 request? Throttle will limit max sent request but won't guarantee minimum, so if those 300 constant users/s send only 300 requests/s then it is impossible to reach 500 requests per sec.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is something similar to this:

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(500) during (10 minutes))).throttle(
reachRps(300) in (10 seconds),
holdFor(5 minutes),
reachRps(500) in (10 seconds),
holdFor(5 minutes)
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

The throttle will be the upper limit your test, so if you have a constant users per second of 500, but throttle it for 300, it will stay throttled to 300, but then once you increase the throttle to 500, you should see the rps rise to that threshold, given `constantUsersPerSec(500)` gives you enough traffic to get you to that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the period showed in your graph is the initial period of the test, where to 12:21 from ~12:31 is reached 300 rps. after that, the gatling will hold for 5 minutes and then make 500 rps by more 10 seconds. You waited 10s + 5 min + 10s + 5min?